# Generate a fingerprint (unique id) for each element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tracking

I am trying to generate a fingerprint for each element in html body.

**My First attempt** was looping all the elements in body and assigning an ID to it.

For now I am taking an input tag to assign

```
var i = 0;
$.each($('#container').find("input"), function(key, value) {
   $(this).attr("data-index", this.tagName.toLowerCase() + "-" + i);
});
```

But if I add an input tag dynamically in between two input tags, then I would have to re-assign all the data-index, which I do not want to do.

Also I do not want to keep track of last added ID.

**For Second attempt** I was thinking of generating a fingerprint depending on the input tag attributes, so that the fingerprint is unique for that page.

Note that, any time if the page is opened, same finger print value should be generated.

Is this way correct?
If yes then, how to generate that fingerprint?

If no then, Please can any one redirect me to some other way of doing it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest a GUID (Globally Unique IDentifier), but then you said you wanted the same value every time the page is generated.  Since that's the case, I suggest some sort of "unique random number generator" that uses a constant seed.  I have no idea if such a thing exists, but such a system would give your already-existing tags the same fingerprint each time the page is loaded, and then when tags are dynamically added, a new (but same as the previous page load) fingerprint would be generated.

The trick there is to create said "unique random" number generator.  Alternatively, you could just use a non-unique random number generator to BUILD a guid.  ie., "Give me the next 10 random numbers between 0 and 9" and there's your ID.  It's exceedingly unlikely that you'd generate two fingerprints of equal value that way.  Just don't forget to have a seed for the generator.

I don't know anything about this project, but here's a seedable generator supposedly: http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html

Comment: You can in this case just use a global counter starting from 0 or 1 as in OPs first attempt as it does not matter what the actual values are (and no risk of collisions).

Comment: @Russell Uhl Thank you for the answer. I will think about it and let you know. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @K3N I do not want it like that. Because I am trying to do something with that unique numbers in future. Thanks for the answer.